# Find the merging node of two linked lists?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

```
MergePoint (LinkList list1, LinkList list2){
p = list1.head;
q = list2.head;
while (p.next!=null && q.next!=null){
    if (p.next == q.next){
        System.out.print(p.value + " is the Merging node");
        return;
    }
    p=p.next;
    q=q.next;
}
```

}

I'm trying to solve a problem to find out the merging node of 2 linked lists. 
Before looking at other solutions, I decided to write my code and then compare to the other existing solutions.
The approach ive taken here is to find the common node that both the list pointers are pointing to.
Do you agree with this code or is there something im missing here?

Comment: I love helping with homework questions -- why not?

Comment: It won't work obviously.

Comment: @Irfy Nothing wrong with helping homework questions (as I have myself here,) just from what I've seen on SO, it's helpful to include the "homework" tag when posting homework questions, just so those answering know :) (the was I answer a homework question will differ, that's the reason.)

Comment: Guys, this is not a homework question. This is an interview question at Amazon and I am stuck. I've read the rules and regulations of this site and NO i'm not here to get help for my homework. So before you give me a big lecture on asking help for homework, do me a favor and READ MY QUESTION AGAIN ! I asked for guidance,tips and NOT A SOLUTION.

Comment: @joshhendo Ah, good point. The "giving him the fish" vs. "teaching him how to fish" argument :-)

Comment: @Naveen Hmmm... I guess in that situation you wouldn't have time to learn fishing. ;-) I updated my answer.

Comment: @Irfy I'm in a state where "giving the fish" or "teach him to fish" wont work. I'm in a stage where "i should know to fish" by now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will only work for the special class of cases where the merging node is in the same *position* in both the lists. I don't think there's an easy, **sub-O(n^2)** way to do this -- in other words, you'll need to compare every node of one list, with every next of second list, and vice versa.

```
MergePoint (LinkList list1, LinkList list2) {
    p = list1.head;
    while (p != null) {
        q = list2.head;
        while (q != null) {
            if (p == q){
                    System.out.print(p.value + " is the Merging node");
                    return;
            }
            q = q.next;
        }        
        p = p.next;
    }    
}
```

Comment: @user664174 Your edit was rejected because it doesn't make any sense to completely change an existing solution -- you should add your own solution, if it is different from any other proposed.

Comment: I think in this solution, the complexity should be O(n*m) because you can not assume both linked lists have the same length.

Answer (score 2):

Three solutions come to mind.

First, the nested loop Irfy posted. It uses constant memory but O(N*M) time, where N and M are the lengths of the two lists.

Second, you can trade space for time, by putting every node of one list into a HashSet first, then walking the other list and doing lookups into the HashSet. Because that lookup is O(1), the total time is O(N+M) (building the hashtable and walking the other list). However, the trade-off is O(N) space required for the table.

Third, if you're allowed to modify the data at least temporarily, you can make one of the lists circular (by connecting the next pointer of its last node to the first) and then use the algorithms described by Stepanov in Elements of Programming to solve the problem in O(N+M) time and O(1) space, because you know that one of the lists is now circular, whereas the other is P-shaped: it starts with its own part and eventually hits the circle of the other list. The place where it hits is called the connection point, and Stepanov gives you an algorithm to find it. Finally, you just unhook the last node again.

The algorithms in question are actually available in the sample chapter, which you can download here:

http://www.elementsofprogramming.com/book.html

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if the "merging nodes" are at the same position in the list.

For example, let's say you have two linked lists...

List 1 has 5 nodes (nodes A, B, C, D, E)
List 2 has 6 nodes (nodes V, W, X, Y, C, D)

Obviously the common node is C. What you seem to be looking for in your code is the node that points to the common node (don't know if it really has a name, merging node is as good as anything,) so in this case you are looking for A and Y.

Your code will do something like this:

```
A.next == V.next? no
B.next == W.next? no
C.next == X.next? no
```

and so on and so forth. This is in the format [Element from List 1 compared with Element from List 2]

What you really want to do is compare the first element of List 1 with all the elements of List 2. Then, if you don't find it, compare the second element of List 1 with all the elements of list 2, and continue to do this so on and so forth.

Since this sounds like a homework question, I won't give you the answer (but I will give you a hint: you will probably need nested loops,) but if you have any further questions with implementing it, then ask away.

Also, may want to look at a special case for the head node, in case the first node in either list is the common node. In this case, you're only comparing the "next" node, meaning the very first one won't ever match if it is the common node between any of the two lists.

Comment: Thanks ! The kind of problem scope i was looking for was very minimal and the instance of the problem I had in mind was exactly the same as you described. In that case, I will use an outer loop for the first list and an inner loop for the second list and then compare. But you mentioned "comparing elements" versus "comparing the next pointers" ? Its comparing the next pointers right? Because elements can be repeated in the lists.

Comment: Element is the actual object, next pointer is a pointer pointing to an element (or object, same thing in this instance.)